# What is then().extract().body().jsonPath().getString("") doing?

Tags: java, cucumber

I have this method in my `Cucumber` test:

```
public void validateError(String name, DataTable errorTable) {
  Map<String, String> error = errorTable.asMap(String.class, String.class);
  String result = then().extract().body().jsonPath().getString("");
  then().statusCode(Integer.parseInt(error.get("errorCode")));
  Assertions.assertThat(result).contains(error.get("errorMessage"));
}
```

It fails on `then().extract().body().jsonPath().getString("")` with:

> Caused by: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'B', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.

I'm trying to understand what `then().extract().body().jsonPath().getString("")`. Is it trying to extract the result from `name`? That would make sense as name is Bob in this case. I was expecting the line to extract the result from a json string though.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how the code you provide compiles because I've not seen, then(), used liked that before, unless it's custom method you created.
I've seen then() used in function programming style like the following.

```
Response response = given()
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON)
                .when()
                .get("/posts")
                .then()
                .extract().response();
```